# If a particle can exert a force on itself,then can we define a whole lot of newtonian mechanics corresponding to it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, particle-physics, research-level

I think that it may be a broad question to be answered but if small amount of discussion is possible then it would be very helpful for all of us.

Basically,I asked a question on this website a few days ago for the confirmation of a concept and the question was about the interaction of a particle with itself.The discussion lead to mixed reactions from the respected users on this website.

As some users said that a particle can exert a force on Itself so I assume that it is true. So I think that if we have got the force then we can define concepts of potential energy,linear and angular momentum,torque etc. corresponding to it. Basically we can define several concepts by using this concept of force.

So,I don't want the users to do homework but I just want the **click** or the **start** of this different kind of mechanics in which we can define new concepts of self energy,momentum etc.

But the major concern is that can we define such new concepts?

Comment: You can define anything you want. I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Aren't these concepts already defined within Newtonian mechanics? The only thing violated here is Newton's Third Law (and that's only true assuming a point particle). Once you relax Newton's Third Law, a self-force is ultimately just an ordinary force. The momentum that the particle gains from this is the same as the usual momentum, and so on.

Comment: One part of an object can have a gravitational effect on another part. Is that what you mean? Example: Different parts of the Earth have gravitational attraction for other parts of the Earth.

Comment: @puppetsock https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/478060/