# Internal force disintegrating a solid body?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Let $M$ be a block on a frictionless surface. Now let us mentally divide (not physically) the block into 2:1 ration (i.e $1/3$ of the left be called $M_1$ and $2/3$ right be called $M_2$). So $M_1$ applies force $F_1$ on $M_2$ and $M_2$ applies force $F_2$ on $M_1$ and by 3rd law they are equal. Hence acceleration of $M_1$ would be $2a$ and that of $M_2$ would be $a$. Shouldn't this deform the block?

Comment: Why would $M_1$ apply a force on $M_2$ at all?

Comment: My understanding is that extended bodies are made up of particle and they exert internal force on each other such that it is overall cancelled.

Comment: In a material at equilibrium the forces exerted by an atom on its neighbours are all zero so there aren't any internal forces.

Answer (score 3):

If the body is isolated, then $a=0$ and the internal forces are $0$. This is a trivial case where there is no longer a contradiction or possibility of the body being torn apart. Therefore, let's consider the scenario of a body that has external forces acting on it.

You are forgetting about external forces being applied to the object. In other words, the net force acting on section $i$ in general is not going to just be $F_i$. You need to specify what external forces are acting on the entire object (and where these forces are being applied). Once you do this, you will find that treating the system as a whole or as many parts should still give you consistent results.

---

Let's take a simple example of a rigid cube of mass $M$ on a frictionless surface, and we push on the left side of this cube to the right with a force of magnitude $F$. Then by Newton's second law the acceleration of the cube is $a=F/M$.

Now let's hypothetically partition our cube into two pieces like you describe, with $1/3$ of the cube as one part on the left and $2/3$ of the cube as the other part on the right. Let's call the interaction force between the two parts $F_{\text{int}}$. Applying Newton's second law to each partition with acceleration $a=F/M$ we have
$$F-F_{\text{int}}=\frac M3\cdot\frac FM$$
$$F_{\text{int}}=\frac{2M}{3}\cdot\frac FM$$
Both equations show that $F_{\text{int}}=2F/3$. Therefore, we don't have any issues here, and this shows the mistake you were making. Each partition has an acceleration of $a=F/M$, and the partition with mass $2M/3$ mass has *twice the net force to the right* in order for it to have the same acceleration as the partition with mass $M/3$. No deformation occurs due to how we hypothetically partition the system.

In fact, you can generalize the above example for the case of partitioning the left side to have mass of $xM$ and the right side to have mass $(1-x)M$ for $0\leq x\leq1$.  You can use the same above analysis to show that the interaction force has a magnitude of $(1-x)F$. This makes sense: the father you are from where the external force is applied, the weaker the interaction force becomes. It even drops to $0$ once we consider the entire block as a single partition ($x=1$), and it is equal to $F$ right at the point of application ($x=0$).

Comment: This answer does not address the OP’s core concern, which is that the internal force at a partition appears to produce different accelerations in the two components. As I explain in my answer, the internal force goes to zero when the object is undeformed and moving rigidly.

Comment: @RLH That isn't true. A rigid body can still have internal forces. How could a rigid disk rotate if not for internal forces?

Comment: @RLH Please see my edit. Internal forces are not always zero for rigid bodies.

Comment: The OP was asking about why 1-d isolated rigid bodies are not disintegrated by internal reactions forces. Rotations and external forces (which you nicely cover) were outside the scope of my comments. (Looking back at the original question, I also notice that the OP has a sign error, listing the accelerations as 2a and a instead of 2a and -a)

Comment: @RLH I suppose we have differing interpretations of the question. The OP doesn't specify an isolated object. And that scenario seems trivial, as then $a=0$ and nothing is really happening.

Comment: I took "frictionless plane" to indicate "isolated system", and the lack of mention of any force other than the internal force to mean that such forces aren't there. My answer was aimed at the implied "how do we know that the internal force won't tear the system apart?"

Comment: @RLH Yeah, if you only consider the case where there are no internal forces, then it does make sense that the internal forces cannot tear the system apart.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your intuition is correct. The piece that you're missing is the *constitutive relationship* that describes how the force $F$ between the pieces depends on their relative position and velocity.

A decent model for most materials is that the constitutive forces act like some combination of a "spring" holding the pieces together, and a "friction damper" that makes their relative motion slow down (you can think of this combination like the mechanism on an automatic door closer).

The spring-damper forces are at equilibrium (zero force) when the block is undeformed and not changing shape, so that the block is moving like the rigid object you expect ($F=0$ gives $a=0$ in your model).

If something did disturb the pieces of the block (i.e. deform the whole block), then the spring-damper constitutive forces would pull it back into shape. The strength of the friction in the damper would determine whether it settles quickly back into shape (for large friction) or "rings" by having the parts of the block oscillate outward and inward (for small friction).

Comment: The OP isn't asking about a physical scenario where the two sections are behaving differently. They just have a misconception about how partitioning the system in different ways seems to yield contradictory results.

Comment: @aaronstevens I disagree. The OP has (to use more formal language) put a free body diagram around each of two portions of a distributed rigid body, and asked why the internal force at the boundary does not cause the pieces to have different accelerations. The answer is first that the force is zero when the body is undeformed and not becoming deformed (the context of a frictionless surface implies the OP is thinking no external forces), and second that if the body were allowed to deform, there would be extra (restorative) dynamics in that mode

Answer (score 1):

Actually you haven't truly addressed as to what kind of material we are dealing with over here, so let me dissect it into two types:

1. Totally rigid
2. Jelly like

**Totally Rigid Bodies**

For objects made up of materials behaving as such as soon as an internal force tries to deform the object an opposite restoring force is generated which balances it. So here you were missing a restoring force in your calculation.

**Jelly Like Bodies**

In these when an internal force acts on the particle then a deformation is caused which leads to greater or lesser volume than originally it would have.

Also the forces aren't unidirectional and hence the deformation occurs in all direction.

$$\underline {\text {Reality}}$$

No real body is a perfect example of both the given case and hence there always is some kind of deformation.

A significant effect of this can be seen in stars (main internal force being gravity).

[**Note**: It must be noted that since internal forces  cancel each other therefore the center of mass doesn't accelerate even a bit(unless an external unbalanced force acts). ]

---

Suggested Materials:

1. [Does a particle exert force on itself?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/478060/249968)
2. [Neutron Stars](https://youtu.be/udFxKZRyQt4)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making a mistake in the way you are imagining force is being applied on the masses. The scenario where $M_1$ and $M_2$ move with acceleration $2a$ and $a$ respectively is when $F$ is applied on both the bodies separately, imagining both are rigid bodies.

The idea of deformation in your mind, what I perceive is, that if $F$ is applied at either body when they are kept adjacent to each other, difference in acceleration will mean that they should deform. BUT, like Aaron clearly showed you, this is not equivalent to application of $F$ on both bodies independently.

Here the force will be redistributed in such a way, that both the bodies will have same acceleration. The whole idea works only when assuming rigid body condition of $F_{12} = F_{21}$. This is the key. You can read more about $\textbf{strong}$ and $\textbf{weak}$ laws of action and reaction.